# How to handle multiple authentications & redirections in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, selenium-chromedriver

Lets say for example that i have page A that prompts for HTTP basic auth.

If correct login credentials are provided, user is redirected to another B site that has another HTTP Auth.

How would you go about doing that?

I can access 1st page via `user:pass@<domain_url.com>` , but I cannot go further than that (get trough the second auth).

Any suggestions?

Only idea I have is to use http multipass extension in chrome, but I do not know how to load it with data before running tests.

Comment: You are explicitly launching the URL for the first time so you are including credentials in the first URL itself and can able to pass the first page but you are unable to do this for the next pages, because you are not launching any URL out there. I think, you need to use 'alert' concept and you need to switch and then need to enter the credentials. Try with an Alert class and let me know

Answer (score 0):

This was possible with older version of selenium, where you can use alert.authenticate. The support for this is dropped as of Selenium 3.12.0. So if you could use version older than this, you could authenticate like,

```
driver.switch_to.alert.authenticate('user', 'password')
```